# In gimp how to create a silhouette/"Burn" a layer into another layer?

Tags: gimp, blend-modes

Well I have an (set of) image(s) and I wish to create silhouettes out of those. Based on the alpha value of the image (alpha is either 0 or 1 no intermediate values).

The idea I had was to create three layers: a white background layer, a black foreground layer and a third top layer with the image.

Then for the top layer  select the right image each time and would pick a blend/layer mode so that it "burns" the alpha from the top layer on the bottom layer. Then I could just load all images into the layers, set the blend modes and make them visible one by one.

Is this possible, or would I have to go through the lengthy process of creating a selection, and making a path from this selection and then using that path as object to fill in the "black" layer. (which requires many more steps and with around a 100 images to process I'm not looking forward to that).

So say I have this image (and/or with the white replaced by a transparent region):

[image]

And I wish to create the following:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  TBH, I'm a bit lost with your verbal explanation. Can you please share an image showing what you are trying to do?  We like pictures here!  Thanks!

Comment: @BillyKerr just added an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Can't you just do an alpha to selection, and then fill with white? [see example](https://imgur.com/D3eSar6)

Comment: Or even quicker, just lock the alpha channel, then fill with white [see example](https://imgur.com/eTdYMYh).

Comment: @BillyKerr hmm I guess I could do that, though it would still require me to either prepare the images or show a few actions between each display. Instead of one click (make a layer visible) to show the different silhouettes. And switch between silhouette and originally image in real time. Especially the switching back, I don't like making a copy as that violates the one source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways you could do this. Here's one.

1. Right click the image layer and do Alpha to Selection
2. Create a new transparent layer, and make sure you select it in the layers panel
3. Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to fill with FG colour

[image]

Another possibility is to use *Colors > Components > Extract component*, select "Alpha" as the component. Do it on a copy of the image layer if you want to keep the original

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

[image]

Your image is in `Split` mode in a group over a layer filled with the background color, and the group itself is over a layer filled with the silhouette color.

If you want to handle several images, you add them to the group. If you do not want to set every image to `Split` mode, put a layer group in `Split` mode where the image is, and add the images to is in `Normal` mode.

**Edit #1:** why the groups

Layer groups are not just a convenient way to keep layers together. They also act like parentheses do in algebra.

- Without a group the layer stack above is evaluated bottom to top as `(white overlaid_by black) split_by image` and `(white overlaid_by black)` is just `black`
- The presence of the group changes this order to `white overlaid_by (black split_by image)`. Since `black split_by image` is black with a hole that silhouettes the image, the final result is the white showing through the image silhouette.

**Edit #2:** the `Erase` mode (instead of `Split`) works just as well, and could be more appropriate (these blend modes are new and ill-documented)

Comment: is the trick making a "group" - cause I tried this without grouping the layers and that didn't seem to work?

Comment: Yes, see edited answer